# Pass a string into view content pane and print in view header

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I've got a view content pane that show the latest 3 articles with a certain tag. The tag used is passed to the contextual filter as an argument in the panels interface. I need to display the name of the tag that is being passed as an argument above the view (in a header).

How can I print the tag name or a string passed as an argument in the views header?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions:

1) You will need to enable php as a input type for views header. Then place code there to print the tag.

2) Use the theme link in the views and find the template file which is responsible for the output . Override that in your own template directory.